# Confused About Ex-Ante vs. Ex-Post Pricing Representation

Tags: stochastic-discount

This is going to be a really simple question, but I am confused by it. The basic pricing formula is $p_t=E^p_t(m_{t+1}X_{t+1})$, where $p$ is the physical measure. We can also say that $R_{t+1}=\frac{X_{t+1}}{p_{t}}$ ex-post. This is just the definition of returns. This means that $E^l_t(R_{t+1})=\frac{E^l_t(X_{t+1})}{p_t}$, and thus $p_t=\frac{E^l_t(X_{t+1})}{E^l_t(R_{t+1})}$. This is with respect to any measure $l$, including the physical measure(it is just a weighted average). If we choose $l=p$(the arbitrary measure equal to the physical measure) then, by uniqueness of the SDF we can say that $m_{t+1}=\frac{1}{E_t^p(R_{t+1})}$. Obviously there must be something wrong with this reasoning, since it concludes that $m_{t+1}$ is not time-t random. I think the problem must be an ex-post vs. ex-ante kind of thing, basically taking the arbitrary measure expectation on the third line is not as simple as it sounds, but I was wondering if anyone had a better explanation.\

I found this especially confusing because my understanding of the basic discounted cash flow model in corporate finance comes from the $p_t=\frac{E^l_t(X_{t+1})}{E^l_t(R_{t+1})}$ expression. But there must be some reason why this expression only makes economic sense if the arbitrary measure is the risk neutral measure.

Comment: To get uniqueness of the SDF, you need complete markets. In a world with $n$ possible outcomes, complete markets would require $n$ linearly independent securities.

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to my above statements, markets are complete in my above posting. There must be a unique SDF in this situation.

Comment: To give an example, you've said that if a security has an expected price tomorrow of 220 and a 10% expected return, then it's price today is 200. Yes, that basic math is true, but it *doesn't* pin down the stochastic discount factor (unless you're living in a deterministic world). The stochastic discount factor associates a discount rate with every possible future outcome.

Comment: But in my problem I showed, purely mechanically, that the price today is merely the ratio of the expected price tomorrow to the expected return in the physical measure. Carrying the expected return into the numerator expected price then this means that it serves the place of the SDF. There has to be a philosophical reason that you are not allowed to go from the aforementioned identity to the SDF, right?

Answer (score 1):

To get uniqueness of the SDF, you need complete markets. In a world with $n$ possible outcomes, complete markets would require $n$ linearly independent securities. Without complete markets, the SDF is not unique.

#### Simple Example: 2 possible outcomes, 1 security

Imagine there are two states of the world and I represent probability measures and random variables as two-dimensional vectors. Let:

$$ \mathbf{p} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \quad  \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \mathbf{m}^{(a)} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{3} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \quad \mathbf{m}^{(b)} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

Let's imagine the price of security $x$ is 1. Both $\mathbf{m}^{(a)}$ and $\mathbf{m}^{(b)}$ correctly price the security since $\sum_i p_i m^{(a)}_i x_i = \sum_i p_i m^{(b)}_i x_i = 1$.

Comment: Markets are complete in my problem.